# How do I alternate between two Ajax method on click and update my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js

Using knockout, I want to be able to call a different Ajax method and update my HTML. I have one button on my screen, it calls a different method (just for show).

For now I'm trying to do this with one method: "GetPopularChannelResult" However, when I try this and combine it with the mapping plugin, I noticed that data is returned, but my model does not update. This is on page load.

I also want this to work in asynchronously.
I found some articles on loading ajax: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/lazy-loading-observable-in-knockoutjs.html
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Asynchronous-Dependent-Observables

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" data-bind="click: toggleChannelButton(), text: btnText()"></button>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" id="spinner" class="ajax-loader" alt="ajax loader" />
        @* TODO: link to a video page *@
        <section id="channelResult" class="hide" data-bind="foreach: channel.data.records">
            <p data-bind="text: username"></p>
            <video width="400" height="400" controls>
                <source data-bind="attr: { src: videoUrl }" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <p data-bind="text: description"></p>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

var channelIdFromUrl = $.url().param('channelId');
var pageFromUrl = $.url().param('page');

// The ViewModel
my.vm = function () {

    var channel = {
            code: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
            data: [
                {
                    count: ko.observable(0),
                    records: [
                        {
                            liked: ko.observable('0'),
                            foursquareVenueId: ko.observable(null),
                            userId: ko.observable(0),
                            private: ko.observable(0),
                            likes: ko.observableArray([{}]),
                            thumbnailUrl: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            explicitContent: ko.observable(0),
                            vanityUrls: ko.observableArray([{}]),
                            verified: ko.observable(1),
                            avatarUrl: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            comments: ko.observableArray([{}]),
                            entities: ko.observableArray([{}]),
                            videoLowURL: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            permalinkUrl: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            username: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            description: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            tags: ko.observableArray([{}]),
                            postId: ko.observable(0),
                            videoUrl: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            created: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            shareUrl: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                            myRepostId: ko.observable(0),
                            promoted: ko.observable(0),
                            reposts: ko.observableArray([{}])
                        }
                    ],
                    nextPage: ko.observable('0'),
                    size: ko.observable('0'),
                    anchorStr: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
                    previousPage: ko.observable(null),
                    anchor: ko.observable('waiting for data')
                }
            ],
            success: ko.observable('waiting for data'),
            error: ko.observable('waiting for data')
        },

        getRecords = function () {
            // It returns undefined first round, until json returns...
            return my.vm.channel.data.records;
        },

        channelData = {
            ChannelId: ko.observable(channelIdFromUrl),
            Page: ko.observable(pageFromUrl)
        },

        // TODO: work on this toggle later
        //isPopular = ko.observable(true),
        //toggleChannelButton = function() {

        //    if (this.IsPopular()) {
        //        this.IsPopular(false);
        //        self.btnText('Get Popular');
        //    } else {
        //        this.IsPopular(true);
        //        self.btnText('Get Recent');
        //    }
        //},
        //btnText = ko.observable('Get Recent'),


        loadChannelPopularCallback = function (json) {
            var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(json);
            ko.mapper.fromJS(parsedJson, {}, my.vm.channel);
        },
        loadPopularChannel = function() {
            my.VineDataService.getVineItems(my.vm.loadChannelPopularCallback, channelData, "GetPopularChannelResult");
        };

    return {
        channel: channel,
        channelData: channelData,
        loadChannelPopularCallback: loadChannelPopularCallback,
        getRecords: getRecords,
        loadPopularChannel: loadPopularChannel
        //IsPopular: isPopular,
        //toggleChannelButton: toggleChannelButton,
        //btnText: btnText
    };
}();

my.vm.loadPopularChannel();
ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

});

**JS dataservice.js**

```
// Depends on scripts:
//                         ajaxservice.js
(function (my) {
    "use strict";
    my.VineDataService = {
        getVineItems : function (callback, channelData, method) {
            my.ajaxService.ajaxGetJson(method, channelData, callback);
        }
    };
}(my));
```

**ajax service**

```
// ajaxService
// Depends on scripts:
//                         jQuery
(function (my) {
    var serviceBase = '/Home/',
        getSvcUrl = function (method) { return serviceBase + method; };

    my.ajaxService = (function () {
        var ajaxGetJson = function (method, jsonIn, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: getSvcUrl(method),
                type: 'GET',
                data: ko.toJS(jsonIn),
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (json) {
                    callback(json);
                }
            });
        },
            ajaxPostJson = function (method, jsonIn, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: getSvcUrl(method),
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ko.toJSON(jsonIn),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (json) {
                        callback(json);
                    }
                });
            };
        return {
            ajaxGetJson: ajaxGetJson,
            ajaxPostJson: ajaxPostJson
        };
    })();
}(my));
```

**My Namespace**

```
var my = my || {}; //my namespace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the previous post mentions, just call one method and handle the logic using a boolean observable to call a different method and toggle it on each call:

**Markup:**

```
<div data-bind="text:results"></div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: getResults, value:btnText()" />
```

**JS:**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.getPopular = ko.observable(true);
    self.results = ko.observable('displaying POPULAR results...');
    self.btnText = ko.observable('Get Recent');

    self.getResults = function () {
        if(self.getPopular())
        {
            self.getPopular(false);
            self.results('displaying RECENT results...')
            self.btnText('Get Popular');            
        }
        else
        {
            self.getPopular(true);
            self.results('displaying POPULAR results...')
            self.btnText('Get Recent');
        }
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**Working example** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bT38w/)

Comment: I believe this is what I needed. Thank you and @TGH

Comment: I was not able to arrive to the solution yet. It seems to be a bit more complicated with Ajax. Mind looking at it again? I posted my code I'm using. Let me know if you need other information.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question around issues with the ajax calls as this answered the original question about how to toggle between two methods. The ajax calls are a new issue which wasn't originally posted.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about that.

Comment: This is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558075/how-do-i-update-my-model-using-ajax-and-mapping-plugin

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the `data-bind`. Instead you can manage the toggle inside the click handler you bind to your element. Keep a flag that you toggle, and use it to decide which method to call.

Comment: Hmm, sounds simple enough, but could you explain the part about if the model is already bound on load, can I still call a different Ajax method with the toggle(On button click). Maybe small sample.

Comment: Yes, you control the body of the click handler, so after you click the first method, you flip the flag on your model. When the button is clicked again, you will check the flag to determine which method to call

Comment: Gotcha, so I just call the other Ajax method, For example, say I have a self.foo(), I and just pass it different Ajax(Json) and it should update the model?

Comment: @TGH my issue was a bit more complicated then I thought, I'm having trouble updating my page with just one method now. I updated the code and cleaned it.